# StringIndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

Im doing a simple program to check if user inputted words are a part of an alien language. 
Im getting an index out of range error message…any help? "String index out of range =" however many letters are inputted.

```
       import java.io.*;
       import java.util.*;
       import static java.lang.System.*;

    public class AlienWords{
       public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);

          out.print("Enter a word: ");
          String str = scan.nextLine();

          char d = str.charAt(str.length());

       int florb = 0;
       int zith = 0;
       int wooble = 0;
       int zarf = 0;

             if (str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(str.length())){
          florb++;
       }
             if (str.indexOf("cj") != -1 || str.indexOf("wq") != -1) {
          wooble++;
       }
             if (str.length() % 2 == 1 && str.indexOf('z') == -1){
          zith++;
       }
             if (str.length() % 2 == 0 && str.indexOf('k') == -1){
          zith++;
       }
             if(Character.isUpperCase(d)){
          zarf++;
       }
             else {
          out.println("This is not an alien word.");
             } 

          }
       }
```

Comment: In the future, please post the exact stack trace.  It will include the line number.

Answer (score 2):

`str.length()-1` is what you're looking for.

You said the error message you're getting is this: `"String index out of range =" however many letters are inputted.`.  The "however many letters are inputted" in this case is your compiler telling you what index it attempted to access (but was out of range).  Indexes for `String`s start at `0`, as such, the index of the last character will be 1 less than the total number of characters in the `String`.

Comment: @user2934559 No problem, just be sure to mark the answer as accepted so your question can be marked as answered.